# Is it common for anti-war groups to oppose nuclear power?

Tags: nuclear-weapons, japan

I came across the article ['Don't make the mistake we did': Fukushima survivor to Queensland](http://www.brisbanetimes.com.au/queensland/dont-make-the-mistake-we-did-fukushima-survivor-to-queensland-20130312-2fy0j.html#ixzz2Nb3UWUDm), which mentions the Japanese organization Peace Boat ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_Boat), [official website](http://www.peaceboat.org/english/)) opposing uranium mining in Australia. The Brisbane Times described the organization as a "disaster relief organisation", but a brief look at the Wikipedia article and their home page suggests that they're primarily an anti-war organization, with a bit of environmentalism thrown in. They have provided some help to those [affected by war](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_Boat#Vietnam_Defoliate_Victim_Support_Campaign) and by the [Tohoku earthquake and tsunami](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88#.E6.9D.B1.E6.97.A5.E6.9C.AC.E5.A4.A7.E9.9C.87.E7.81.BD.E7.B7.8A.E6.80.A5.E6.94.AF.E6.8F.B4) (Japanese language Wikipedia link), though.

What I suspect, but is probably beyond the scope of this stack exchange, is that Peace Boat is mainly opposed to nuclear power because it makes it easier to build nuclear weapons, and that the Fukushima dai-ichi accident is merely being used as a supporting argument for a position it already held.

What I would like to know is whether it is or was common for anti-war groups to oppose nuclear power, even when they aren't politically active on any other environmental issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Some recent examples:

- [Ofog Stockholm at *10000 against nuclear power*](http://www.ofog.org/bilder/ofog-stockholm-p%C3%A5-10-000-mot-k%C3%A4rnkraft)
- [Vredesactie Belgium against nuclear power](http://vredesactie.be/article.php?id=685), citing that nuclear power is inherently linked to nuclear arms
- [War Resisters International report on attack against Russian anti-nuclear camp](http://www.wri-irg.org/fr/node/5719) — not sure if that camp was really about peaceful nuclear power

Longer ago, in 1981, [Dorothy Nelkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorothy_Nelkin) published an article on the question in the [Bulletin of the Atomic Scientists](http://www.thebulletin.org/):

- Nelkin, Dorothy. "Anti-nuclear connections: power and weapons." Bull. At. Sci.;(United States) 37.4 (1981). From the abstract:

> The anti-nuclear power and the peace movements, while sharing many concerns have only recently begun to link their activities and participation. Because public criticism of corporate policy is easier to mobilize than criticism of weapons policy, those opposed to the potential spread of nuclear weapons have kept their goals and activities narrowed to retain their momentum. The two movements are analyzed and compared in terms of their organization and their responses to efforts made to establish links. Signs of a convergence reflect public concern for radiation safety and nuclear proliferation as both movements broadened their goals to include moral and political themes. Recent shifts in military policy have also brought the groups closer together.

Excepts can be read through [Google Books](http://books.google.se/books?id=wgoAAAAAMBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).  On page 38, we read:

> Mobilization for Survival represents the first peace group to officially include both the banning of nuclear power and military weapons on its official agenda.  It has demanded a moratorium on the construction of nuclear power plants and weapons facilities, the mining, milling and transportation of uranium, and on weapons research, production, development, and testing.

So, **yes**, it is common for anti-war groups to oppose nuclear power.

Comment: @DVK On a side note, the third link in my article illustrates one reason why many activists might hesitate to join a protest camp in Russia.  In Sweden being arrested by police means landing in a soft cell while entitled to vegan food.  In Russia it could be quite a lot worse.  A Venezuelan who was arrested at a peace camp in northern Sweden a few years ago was quite impressed by the niceness of Swedish police (we did have people awake at all time out of fear for people who might *not like us*; they do exist in Sweden).

Comment: (1) I am not asking for protesting IN Russia. I'm asking for at least for position paper protesting stuff in russian from outside (e.g. Japan).

Comment: (2) If you exclaim that you are against violence, but when a "normal" person gets a knife to protect himself against a 2ft psychopath with a knife, you can't claim that you're against violence when you force the "normal" person to get rid of the knife but not the psychopath, because you are justifyably afraid of the latter. An intellectually honest approach would be to refuse pressuring the "nice guy" just because he's a nice guy, *because you are effectively helping the psychopath that you yourself are admittedly not happy with being in power*.

Comment: ... or, as someone much more eloquent than myself once put it: "Since pacifists have more freedom of action in countries where traces of democracy survive, pacifism can act more effectively against democracy than for it. Objectively the pacifist is pro-Nazi." - George Orwell

Comment: @DVK (1) I'm sure that such position papers be found (you may choose to ask a separate question), although they might still choose to focus on the country where they live, and (2) If a psychopath attacks me my first choice is to run away, my second choice to defend myself. I don't think society can function without police, but I do think military solutions are almost never the most sensible one.  As for the George Orwell quote, I think that is dated; there have been many successful non-violent resistances since he said that, the world now is very different from the world in 1941.

Comment: @DVK a 2ft psychopath, or a 2 metre psychopath?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - oupsie ... And THAT's how you crash $2billion worth of NASA hardware into Mars :)

Comment: @gerrit - the point with the psychopath wasn't him attacking YOU and your chioces, but him attacking someone else and you limiting that someone else's choices. My problem with pacifists isn't their refusal to use violence to confront evil (I still disagree with the idea, but many people have many stupid ideas like doing drugs or jumping off bridges); my problem with pacifists is that they limit other people's freedom to confront evil, because they are too blind to see a difference between violence done to stop violence and violence done to achieve some random goal.

Comment: BTW, the only difference between police and military is the scope of who they confront - individual perps vs. larger organized groups. But fundamentally, they are the same - a group organized and sanctioned by the state to use violent force to uphold the law.

Comment: @DVK, I don't think pacifists limit other peoples choices to defend themselves against psychopaths, although most probably do want to limit the number of weapons overall, therefore reducing the damage that a psychopath can do.  That's in fact one of the arguments for TOTAL nuclear disarmament (criminals, terrorists or psychopaths obtaining WOMD — not good).  As for military vs. police, that's worth discussing elsewhere.  I partially agree.  Military rarely addresses criminality.  Military are mostly used to defend national interests, rarely to uphold the law.  I propose to move to [Chat].

Comment: I will be cleaning up the comments in a couple of days, gerrit if you think there's anything in the comments that you would like to add to your answer, please do so.